# Resources$NotFoundException after configuration change in dynamic feature module

Tags: android, onconfigurationchanged, dynamic-feature-module

I'm currently experimenting with dynamic feature modules and came across a strange problem. I handle configuration changes by implementing the `onConfigurationChanged` method in my Activity and defining it in the manifest by adding `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden|uiMode"`. This works fine for "normal" apks, however - when I do this in dynamic feature modules I get a `Resources$NotFoundException` after the device rotated - for resources that have already been resolved correctly before the rotation. So from my point of view I'm missing something to handle correctly for the rotation - I already tried reapplying the `SplitCompat.install(<Context>)` in the `onConfigurationChanged`, but this does also not work. Anyone got any idea what I'm doing wrong?

This happens for me with the com.google.android.play:core:1.6.4 library.

```
2019-11-06 10:33:33.101 5933-5933/? W/ResourceType: No known package when getting value for resource number 0x7e0d00a8
2019-11-06 10:33:33.102 5933-5933/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-11-06 10:33:33.103 5933-5933/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.jumio.dynamicfeature, PID: 5933
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7e0d00a8
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:339)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5496)
```

Comment: Please try this in your app gradle file:     bundle {
        language {
            // Specifies that the app bundle should not support
            // configuration APKs for language resources. These
            // resources are instead packaged with each base and
            // dynamic feature APK.
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }

Answer (score 4):

Finally found the issue that was causing the problem - it seems that the `SplitCompat.install(<Context>)` needs to be called in `onConfigurationChanged` - but before `super.onConfigurationChanged()` is called! This has to be done because `super.onConfigurationChanged` triggeres the `onConfigurationChanged` method inside the fragments where I update some parts of the ui.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration configuration) {
    SplitCompat.install(this);

    super.onConfigurationChanged(configuration);

    ...
}
```

I also encountered an issue afterwards that Theme attributes could not be resolved after rotation - turns out that if fragments are used, the `getTheme` method in the activity needs to be adapted as well - themeId is the same id that is also set with setTheme in the onCreate method.

```
@Override
public Resources.Theme getTheme() {
    Resources.Theme theme = super.getTheme();
    if (themeId != 0) {
        theme.applyStyle(themeId, true);
    }
    return theme;
}
```